# How to make Active Record query that allows to find by part of value

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model ticket.rb. This model has :number column.
I decided to make method that should search tickets in database by first 7 digits of ticket number. I can't get how to make Active Record query on database to achive my goal.
I've tried

```
ticket = Ticket.where("(/^\S{7}) number = ?", "#{n}")
```

but this has no sense, searched answer for two days.

Comment: Have you tried like operator in your query

Comment: Yes, LIKE operator is what I was looking for, thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

misa,

This should do it:

```
# Makes numbers like '123' become '0000123'
# or takes first 7 digits if number is longer than 7 digits:
n = sprintf("%07d", n).first(7)

# Searches for anything starting with those 7 digits.
tickets = Ticket.where("number like '#{n}%'")
```

If you think there's only one such ticket in the db, just do `find_by` instead of `where`:

```
ticket = Ticket.find_by("number like '#{n}%'")
```

If your `number` field is not a string, but a number, you'll need to type cast by doing:

```
ticket = Ticket.find_by("CAST(number AS varchar) like '#{n}%'")
```

Let me know if you need more help.